# Any chance to "wrap" this native iOS API call into async / await?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, async-await

Consider this iOS 6 API call:

```
eventStore.RequestAccess(EKEntityType.Event, (granted, error) => {
if(granted)
{
    events = this.GetLocalCalendarEvents(eventStore);
}});
```

I have some code that accesses the calendar and reads events. On iOS5 this just works but on iOS6 I have to ask for access first and, if granted, start reading then.
I was wondering if I can somehow wrap this into a combination of async/await to hide the ugly delegate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
public Task<bool> DoSomethingAsync()
{
   var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

   //Call some asynchronous Apple API
   NSSomeAppleApi.DoSomething(error =>
   {
      if (error != null)
         taskSource.SetException(new Exception(error.LocalizationDescription));
      else
         taskSource.SetResult(true);
   });

   return taskSource.Task;
}
```

Comment: Nice!! Didn't know about TaskCompletionSource()!